# How to send a value of td to views.py which is added to table dynamically in ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I  am trying to create the custom calendar in django.
     It has next and previous button to view next or previous month respectively.
     I have added the dates,year and month name dynamically in a jquery,ajax function.
     When the user clicks the NEXT button,I want the current loaded month name to go back to views.py.I am unable to catch the month name since its dynamically added.
 My code is : Search.html

```
    $("#next").click(function()
 {

var input_string = $("#cal_mon").val();


alert("i======",input_string);
console.log("i",input_string);

$.ajax({
                    url : "/getnextmonth/",
                    type : "POST",
                    dataType: "json",

                     data :
                     {
                        client_response  : input_string,

                        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
                     },
                        success : function(json) 
                        {

                        var date =  json.server_response;
                        var day =  json.server_response1;
                        var year =  json.server_response2;
                        var month =  json.server_response3;
                        var list_months =  json.server_response4;
                        var dates_as_per_daysinmonth =  json.server_response5;

                        var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];     
                        var table = document.getElementById("eve_calendar");

                        var tbody = document.getElementById('tbody');

                        $("#row_1").empty();
                        $("#row_2").empty();
                        $("#row_3").empty();
                        $("#row_4").empty();
                        $("#row_5").empty();

                        var row1 = document.getElementById("row_1");
                        var row2 = document.getElementById("row_2");
                        var row3 = document.getElementById("row_3");
                        var row4 = document.getElementById("row_4");
                        var row5 = document.getElementById("row_5");


                    <!-- Month name --> 
                    var tr_mon = document.getElementById("event_month");
                    var td_mon = document.getElementById("cal_mon");
                    var td_nextb = document.getElementById("next_b");


                                    //alert(month);


                <!-- leap year -->  

                        if(year%400 ==0)
                        {
                        //// alert("leap year");
                        }
                        else if (year%100 ==0)
                        {
                    //  alert("not leap year");
                        }
                        else if (year%4 ==0)
                        {
                    //  alert("leap year");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                    //  alert("not");
                        }


                    <!-- alert(month_name); -->                                


                    for (var i=0;i<month;i++)
                  { 
                          if(i==month-1)
                        { 

                             td_mon.textContent = list_months[i] + " "+ year;                           
                           //  document.getElementById("cal_mon").value =list_months[i];

                         }
                  }

                        tr_mon.appendChild(td_mon); 
                        tr_mon.appendChild(td_nextb); 

                      <!-- no. of days in Month  -->    

                        var no_of_days;

                            if(month!=2)
                        {
                            if(month==9||month==4||month==6||month==11)
                                 no_of_days=30;
                           else
                                no_of_days= 31;
                        }
              else   {
                        no_of_days=  (year%4==""  && year%100!="" ? 29 : 28);
                     }

                    //    alert(no_of_days);    


                        <!-- add dates as per month-->


                        var flag2=1;

                        //tbody.appendChild(tr_mon);


                         for (var n =0;n < dates_as_per_daysinmonth.length;n++)
                {           

                          for(var m=0;m<dates_as_per_daysinmonth[n].length;m++)
                        {
                            console.log(dates_as_per_daysinmonth[n][m]);

                            if(flag2==1)
                            {
                               var cell = document.createElement("td");
                               if (dates_as_per_daysinmonth[n][m]==0)
                               {
                               }
                               else   
                                     cell.textContent = dates_as_per_daysinmonth[n][m];
                               row1.appendChild(cell);

                            }


                            if(flag2==2)
                            {
                               var cell = document.createElement("td");
                               if (dates_as_per_daysinmonth[n][m]==0)
                               {
                               }
                               else 
                                     cell.textContent = dates_as_per_daysinmonth[n][m];

                               row2.appendChild(cell);

                            }


                            if(flag2==3)
                            {
                               var cell = document.createElement("td");
                               if (dates_as_per_daysinmonth[n][m]==0)
                               {
                               }
                               else 
                                   cell.textContent = dates_as_per_daysinmonth[n][m];
                               row3.appendChild(cell);

                            }

                            if(flag2==4)
                            {
                               var cell = document.createElement("td");
                               if (dates_as_per_daysinmonth[n][m]==0)
                               {
                               }
                               else 
                                      cell.textContent = dates_as_per_daysinmonth[n][m];
                               row4.appendChild(cell);

                            }

                            if(flag2==5)
                            {
                               var cell = document.createElement("td");
                               if (dates_as_per_daysinmonth[n][m]==0)
                               {
                               }
                               else 
                                   cell.textContent = dates_as_per_daysinmonth[n][m];
                               row5.appendChild(cell);

                            }

                            //alert("dt====",dates_as_per_daysinmonth);
                        }

           //               tbody.appendChild(row2);
        ///              }  

                    flag2=flag2+1;

                }       

                   //     tbody.appendChild(tr_mon);
                        tbody.appendChild(row1);
                        tbody.appendChild(row2);
                        tbody.appendChild(row3);
                        tbody.appendChild(row4);
                        tbody.appendChild(row5);

                        table.appendChild(tbody);

                        body.appendChild(table);
                    },


                          error : function(xhr,errmsg,err)
                          {
                            alert(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
                         }
    });
  });


   </script>
```

My views.py function:::

```
     flag34=0
     year_count=0
 @csrf_exempt
 def getnextmonth(request):

    global flag34
    global counter
    if request.POST.has_key('client_response'):


            if(flag34==0):
                counter=0
                flag34=1
         # calendar with events

            month1 = request.POST['client_response']
            counter=counter+1
            print "c",counter

            print "\n getnextmonth:::: new m-=========",month1


            sys_date_time = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %a %H:%M:%S ")
            print sys_date_time
            string1=str(sys_date_time)

            str2=string1[8:10]
            print "str2",str2
            date=int(str2)
            print "date",date

            day=string1[11:13]
            ##    day=int(day)
            print "day",day


            month=string1[5:7]


            year=string1[0:4]

            year=int(year)
            print "year",year

            month=int(month)

            list_months=["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"]


            month2=month+counter
            print "month",month2

            print month+year

            if(month2==12):
                counter=0
                flag34=0
                cal = calendar.monthcalendar(year, month2)


            else:
                cal = calendar.monthcalendar(year, month2)
            print "next mon====",cal

            x = request.POST['client_response']


            print "======================================================================="
            print "value xxxxxx==",x
            print "======================================================================="

            response_dict = {}

            response_dict.update({'server_response': date })
            response_dict.update({'server_response1': day })
            response_dict.update({'server_response2': year })
            response_dict.update({'server_response3': month2 })
            response_dict.update({'server_response4': list_months })
            response_dict.update({'server_response5': cal })


            print "\njson list"

            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_dict), content_type='application/json')
    else:
            return render_to_response('Search.html',    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Please suggest something. I just want to know if we are creating and assigning the value to some value in UI dynamically, and what is the better way to send that value back in views.py and do some calculation and send some new values for updation.

**NOTE**::: OHH! I was just trying for incrementing the month by using global variable, but thats not a permanent code! I know I may be wrong ! I am new in all this ! Please correct me !
Please help ! I am not better in UI technologies !

Thanks in advance !
-Snehali

Comment: Argh: globals in a view handler. Please think about what effects they will have once more than one person is using your app at a time.

Comment: OHH! I was just trying it for incrementing the month ! I know I may be wrong ! I am new in all this ! Please correct me !